# Preloading images to play animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have to preload approximately **900** images to play the required animation based on the user selection. But before that, I have to check, which images I have to preload. I have approximately **5400** images, which I have extracted from the videos using ***ffmpeg***. And based on the user selection I have to preload the required images. I am also showing how much percentage of preloading is completed.

*Below is the code I am using to preload 900 the images based on the user selection.*

```
function preloadImages(ImagesURL, callback) {
    var img_i;
    var img_j;
    var loaded = 0;
    for (img_i = 0, img_j = ImagesURL.length; img_i < img_j; img_i++) {
        (function (img, src) {
            img.onload = function () {
                updateProgress(); // to show how much is completed
                if (++loaded == ImagesURL.length && callback) {
                    callback();
                }
            };
            img.onerror = function () {
                showCustomMessage("Error occurred while loading files, please refresh the page and try again.");
            };
            img.onabort = function () {};
            img.src = src;
        } (new Image(), ImagesURL[img_i]));
    }
}
```

Now I want to know is there any better method other than this? Or should I use AJAX instead of that, because this function is running absolutely fine on the desktop's but the same method is eating up lot of resources while running on the iPad or handheld devices.

Comment: Are you sure you really want to do this? It doesn't really make sense at all. Lets say the avg size of a picture you loaded from your vid is 50K, and you need to load 900 pictures... that's 45MB!!! what are you trying to do?!

Comment: @Dekel It even more that 50K when it get undecoded (example: jpeg to raw pixel data).

Comment: I was going for a small images :) and even in such case - you should really rethink about it...

Comment: Why not keep them as a video and load the video instead. There is a lot of good stuff about videos, you can speed them up, jump to times and more.

Comment: @Dekel: The average size of each image is approx 30-40 KB, that means 35 MB should be preloaded before the application is shown to the user.
After that, I will play few animations based on the user selections.

Comment: I really don't envy your users

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I am using this solution because the video support is limited in the handheld devices but for the desktop I am using videos.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir But there are few browsers which doesn't cache videos, and for them I am using images and playing frames instead of videos

Comment: Well, your code seems to be ok. I can't think of another way.

Comment: And also the requirement was to play the videos one after another, but without even a single jerk. Because they are connected to each other.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir what about AJAX? instead of new Image()

Comment: @VarunChakervarti I think AJAX to load images will be a bad idea. The best way to load images is the natural way of `Image`.

Comment: @VarunChakervarti I don't know but I think grouping images into big images will optimize it a bit. maybe big images that contain 10 of the frames at a time. So instead of **900** images you'll have just **90** big images.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Sprite images?

Comment: @VarunChakervarti Yeah something like that.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Each animation is of 30-35 images/frames. And also they are full screen animations.